# How to change Android "config.xml" values for low memory killer

Tags: android, config, low-memory

I'm trying to tune these two low memory killer (lmk) values on my Pixel 4XL with Android 12:

```
<integer name="config_lowMemoryKillerMinFreeKbytesAbsolute">-1</integer>
<integer name="config_lowMemoryKillerMinFreeKbytesAdjust">0</integer>
```

According to [this](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/low-ram), "These thresholds can be configured with the config.xml framework."

How can I change these values? Is there an equivalent "prop" I can set with setprop?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no Android property for setting these thresholds.
They are seen as constants in the code and can be changed only within the [config.xml](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml;l=213)

This is the documentation [link](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/kernel/config#lowmem) where the semantics of these constants is described.

Furthermore it is worth noting that the mentioned constants are relevant only for the [LMKD legacy mode](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/lmkd#kill-strategies), e.g. in case of property `ro.lmk.use_minfree_levels` being set to `true`.

Exploring the [LMKD documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/perf/lmkd) you may find that there are at least 2 alternatives out there:

1. using vmpressure signals
2. using PSI (pressure stall information) monitors